# The menu isn't scaling with the site and on smaller monitors the video / photos are off to the right

Tags: css, html, scale

I asked for help earlier which was amazing and I am grateful for it, but I'm in need of your guys' expert assistance.

http://www.mrandmrsmagic.com is the site I'm working on and after simplifying the code and not having the positioning be an absolute, the menu bar for some odd reason isn't scaling with the site. Also the testimonials tab is cut off, which I'm guessing is due to the width not being long enough?

Also, on smaller monitors (15 inches+), they're saying that the video gallery and photo gallery are off to the right three inches, is there a way I can add padding or a margin to make them stick to the middle like they do with a larger screen? Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...

Your Gallery is in a `div` that has been given a specified position.

e.g

```
#gallery {
    position: relative;
    left: 950px; /* This needs to be removed */
    top: -560px; /* This needs to be removed */
}
```

That will always force the `div` off to the side.

What I *think* you want and correct me if I'm wrong is two columns.

That's actually quite easy to do and I've set up an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/um8qb/) to get you going.

In my example the two columns are floated left and right to give them space in the middle and the two `divs` with the class `.placeholder` provide the hight and width.

If you create something similar replacing each `.placeholder` with your image and gallery respectively then you should be able to keep videos within the main content.

Hopefully this helps.

### Edit

I'll try my best to explain everything properly.

The content div in the example I linked was just there to wrap around the floated columns in that example. You do not need to duplicate it.

The columns are floated left and right to separate the content and place it side-by-side. Adding a float simply means that they are to position themselves as far in the given direction as possible within their parent container.

Floating content breaks the flow of the page though so the parent needs to have the class `.clearfix` added to prevent any content below the column from being disrupted. It also allows the parent to have height.

Positioning the gallery differently for different monitor widths will only work with browsers that understand media blocks within css which ie7 and ie8 do not. You are much, much better off with a two column layout.

Comment: I really appreciate it. Also, do you by chance know why the menu bar isn't scaling with the site? It seems shrunk down and the testimonials tab is missing.

Comment: No problem. The `ul` containing the menu has a padding of 40px which is set by default just add `#cssmenu ul {padding:0;}`to your css and that will fix it.

Comment: Awesome, just one more small question then I'll most certainly be in your debt. While that fixes it, there's still that small gap where it seems to be hidden behind the background. Would I mess with the padding in #cssmenu ul. mrandmrsmagic.com

Comment: Not the padding but the margin. By default the browser is adding a margin of 1em to the top and bottom of the `ul` element. Simply set the css to `#cssmenu ul {padding:0;margin:0}` and that will fix the layout.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to help me, I'm kind of a novice at this (rusty despite me having a degree, I forgot a lot of it over the past year / skills decayed). One last minor question, which I'm sure is easy and I'm just overlooking it. How do I get rid of the small white dots? Once again, I deeply appreciate the knowledge you've imparted on me.

Comment: I didn't even see them! Easy enough; just set the property `list-style: none;` in your ul css. And don't worry about skills degrading. They come back soon enough.

Comment: I feel bad wasting your time like this, I'm sure it's late. But for the video thing, I was a bit confused because there is already like a set gallery, that seems to be fine for larger sized monitors. Can't I just add a positioning tag if the monitor is sub 17 inches, so it shows up right in the center or is that not feasible? I didn't quite understand the jsfiddle thing, since there's already a content div tag.